# Finding out derivative of variables from an expression

Tags: functions

I have the following expression

```
gh=(G^(0,0,1))[0,1,x]+G[1,x];
```

Where `G^(0,0,1)[0,1,x]=D[G[0,1,x],x]`. This is a model expression. Actually I have some large expression with `G` and derivatives. I want to extract the derivative terms. But writing

```
Cases[gh,D[G[__,x],x]]
```

is not giving the first term. How to do this?

Comment: Try examining the FullForm of the expression. This should give you an idea of the pattern to use in Cases.

Comment: You need to use `Derivative[0, 0, 1][G][0, 1, x]` rather than `G^(0,0,1)[0,1,x]`.

Comment: Not clear: Function `G` depends on two or three arguments?

Comment: the expression comes as ```G^(0,0,1)[0,1,x]``` which means first derivative with respect to third argument

Comment: Here is the correct syntax: `gh = D[G[0, 1, x], x] + G[0, 1, x];
Cases[gh, D[G[0, 1, x], x]]`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
    Cases[expr,Derivative[__][_][___],\[Infinity]]
```

The identification of the Derivative construct with three argument list is a bit complicated, as can be seen by Position

```
   exp = Exp[1/(77 D[F[x, y, z], x, {y, 2}, z])]

   Position[exp, _Derivative, \[Infinity]]
```

yields the Head
{{2, 2, 1, 0, 0}}

```
   Position[exp, _Derivative[__], \[Infinity]]
```

yields the Head
{{2, 2, 1, 0, 0}}

```
   Position[exp, Derivative[__][_], \[Infinity]]
```

yields the secondary Head
{{2, 2, 1, 0}}

```
   Position[exp, Derivative[__][_][___], \[Infinity]]
    {{2, 2, 1}}

  exp[[2, 2, 1]]
```

$$F^{(1,2,1)}(x,y,z)$$